# Matlab Box plot handles/property values

Tags: arrays, matlab, boxplot, argument-unpacking

I am trying to access the values used to create a `boxplot()`.

I created a plot:

```
diagram(returns);
```

Found handles of the outliers:

```
o = findobj(diagram,'tag','Outliers');
```

get the data for the outliers:

```
ydata = get(o,'YData');
```

problem is it returns this:

```
ydata = 

    [1x2 double]
    [   -0.1330]
    [1x3 double]
    [       NaN]
    [   -0.0898]
    [       NaN]
```

Because Some of the plots have multiple outliers.  How do I unpack the values of the 1x2 double?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate all rows in the cell array into a single row:

```
ydata = [ydata{:}]
```

And then if you want to ignore NaNs:

```
ydata = ydata(~isnan(ydata))
```